# How to display Json data using checkboxes in my jsp page?

Tags: javascript, json, checkbox

I'm creating a basic website which has 2 drop downs and the way it should work is For the first drop down it should display the data from a select query from the DB and based on the user selection of the first dropdown i want to populate the 2nd dropdown values by using JSON. I have used JSON array and parsing it in my index.jsp page. But I need help displaying the JSON data using checkboxes. Here is my JS code where I'm using a table to display the JSON data but i need checkboxes. I'm new to coding so any help will be appreciated!

Here is my Index.jsp:

```
<div class="programFields">
  <label>Pick a client</label>
  <select id="clientName" name="clientDropDown" onchange="ref()">
  <% while(r.next()){%>
    <option><%= r.getString("acode")%>
    </option>
  <%} %>
  </select>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

and my JS in Index.jsp:

```
function ref() { 
    var code = document.querySelector("select[name=clientDropDown]").value;
    var x, myObj, txt  = '' ;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            txt += "<select>"
            for (x in myObj) {
                txt += "<option>" + myObj[x].payor_id + "</option>";
            }
            txt += "</select>"
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("POST", "Server.jsp", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send( "code=" + code);
}
```

Comment: Where have you put this code? Can you provide some more part of your code?

Comment: if in response contains {"status":"active"} you need to check the checkbox, isn't? an example

Comment: I added the html and javascript code. I'm writing this in my jsp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the HTML you insert:

```js
// For the demo, myObj is already received and parsed
var myObj = [
  {name: "Ted",      id: 0, friend: false},
  {name: "Chandler", id: 1, friend: true },
  {name: "Monica",   id: 2, friend: true },
  {name: "Phoebe",   id: 3, friend: true },
  {name: "Donald",   id: 4, friend: false},
  {name: "Rachel",   id: 5, friend: true },
  {name: "Ross",     id: 6, friend: true },
  {name: "Joey",     id: 7, friend: true }
];

var txt = "";

for (var x in myObj) {
  txt += '<input type="checkbox" value="' + myObj[x].id + '" '
       + (myObj[x].friend ? 'checked' : '') + '>'
       + myObj[x].name
       + '<br />';
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<h3>My friends</h3>
<div id="demo"></div>
```